# Get the HubContext using SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, simple-injector

[This guide](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) does not appear to work for SimpleInjector.

My `OWIN` startup looks like this:

```
container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle();

container.RegisterSingleton(() => new SimpleInjectorSignalRDependencyResolver(_container));
container.RegisterSingleton(() =>
    new HubConfiguration()
    {
        EnableDetailedErrors = true,
        Resolver = _container.GetInstance<SimpleInjectorSignalRDependencyResolver>()
    });

container.RegisterSingleton<IHubActivator, SimpleInjectorHubActivator>();
container.RegisterSingleton<IStockTicker,StockTicker>();
container.RegisterSingleton<HubContextAdapter<StockTickerHub, IStockTickerHubClient>>();
container.RegisterSingleton(() => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager);
container.Verify();

GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = container.GetInstance<SimpleInjectorSignalRDependencyResolver>();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    using (container.BeginExecutionContextScope())
    {
        await next();
    }
});

app.MapSignalR(container.GetInstance<HubConfiguration>());
```

And The `HubContextAdapter` looks like this:

```
public class HubContextAdapter<THub, TClient>
    where THub : Hub
    where TClient : class
{
    private readonly IConnectionManager _manager;

    public HubContextAdapter(IConnectionManager manager)
    {
        _manager = manager;
    }

    public IHubContext<TClient> GetHubContext()
    {
        return _manager.GetHubContext<THub, TClient>();
    }
}
```

And `SimpleInjectorSignalRDependencyResolver` looks like:

```
public class SimpleInjectorSignalRDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    public SimpleInjectorSignalRDependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType) ?? base.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        var @this = (IEnumerable<object>)_serviceProvider.GetService(
            typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(serviceType));

        var @base = base.GetServices(serviceType);

        return @this == null ? @base : @base == null ? @this : @this.Concat(@base);
    }

    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
}
```

And `StockTicker` looks like:

```
public class StockTicker : IStockTicker
{
    private readonly HubContextAdapter<StockTickerHub, IStockTickerHubClient> _context;

    public StockTicker(HubContextAdapter<StockTickerHub, IStockTickerHubClient> context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

When the `StockTicker` ticks and calls all clients to update the client method is not invoked and there is no network traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleInjector wants to instantiate the singletons after verification or after the first `GetInstance` call. This is too early for SignalR and the `StockTicker` and it will take an instance of `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager` before `SimpleInjectorSignalRDependencyResolver` is the resolver.

I chose to change the dependency on `IConnectionManager` to be `Lazy<IConnectionManager>` and the dependency on `IStockTicker` to be `Lazy<IStockTicker>` so that registration became like the following:

```
container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle();

container.RegisterSingleton(() => new SimpleInjectorSignalRDependencyResolver(_container));
container.RegisterSingleton(() =>
    new HubConfiguration()
    {
        EnableDetailedErrors = true,
        Resolver = _container.GetInstance<SimpleInjectorSignalRDependencyResolver>()
    });

container.RegisterSingleton<IHubActivator, SimpleInjectorHubActivator>();
container.RegisterSingleton<IStockTicker,StockTicker>();
container.RegisterSingleton<Lazy<IStockTicker>>(() => new Lazy<IStockTicker>(() => container.GetInstace<IStockTicker>()) );
container.RegisterSingleton<HubContextAdapter<StockTickerHub, IStockTickerHubClient>>();
container.RegisterSingleton(() => new Lazy<IConnectionManager>(() => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager));
container.Verify();
```